# Туманности с меню

Tags: php, mysql

Есть меню. При переходе на ссылку передается параметр id

```
if (@$_POST['save']){

$text=$_POST['content'];
$pole=$_POST['pole'];
$titul=$_POST['titul'];
if (!$text || !$pole || !$titul) {
echo ("Поле не заполнено");
} else {

//Работа непосредственно с главной страницей
if ($id==1){
mysql_query($q = 'INSERT INTO first (`title`, `nazv`,`text`) VALUES (\''.mysql_real_escape_string($titul).'\',\''.mysql_real_escape_string($pole).'\', \''.mysql_real_escape_string($text).'\');') or die (mysql_error().'<br />Query: '.$q);
}
//Добавляем статьи
if ($id==9){
mysql_query($q = 'INSERT INTO stat (`title`, `nazv`,`text`) VALUES (\''.mysql_real_escape_string($titul).'\',\''.mysql_real_escape_string($pole).'\', \''.mysql_real_escape_string($text).'\');') or die (mysql_error().'<br />Query: '.$q);
}  
//Добавляем новости
    if ($id==5){
    mysql_query($q = 'INSERT INTO news (`title`, `nazv`,`text`) VALUES (\''.mysql_real_escape_string($titul).'\',\''.mysql_real_escape_string($pole).'\', \''.mysql_real_escape_string($text).'\');') or die (mysql_error().'<br />Query: '.$q);
    }
    ?>
```

НО не хочет добавлять ничего кроме как по действием ($id==1). Только все что связано с ($id==1) работает а остальные ($id==9)($id==5) не работают. в чем возможная причина?

Полный вариант

```
{*
<?php
$content="";
ob_start();

require_once "conf.php";
dbConnect();
if (@$_POST['save']){

  $text=$_POST['content'];
  $pole=$_POST['pole'];
  $titul=$_POST['titul'];
  if (!$text || !$pole || !$titul) {
    echo ("Поле не заполнено");
    } else {

    //Работа непосредственно с главной страницей
    if ($id==1){
    mysql_query($q = 'INSERT INTO first (`title`, `nazv`,`text`) VALUES (\''.mysql_real_escape_string($titul).'\',\''.mysql_real_escape_string($pole).'\', \''.mysql_real_escape_string($text).'\');') or die (mysql_error().'<br />Query: '.$q);
    }
    //Добавляем статьи
    if ($id==9){
    mysql_query($q = 'INSERT INTO stat (`title`, `nazv`,`text`) VALUES (\''.mysql_real_escape_string($titul).'\',\''.mysql_real_escape_string($pole).'\', \''.mysql_real_escape_string($text).'\');') or die (mysql_error().'<br />Query: '.$q);
    }  
    //Добавляем новости
        if ($id==5){
        mysql_query($q = 'INSERT INTO news (`title`, `nazv`,`text`) VALUES (\''.mysql_real_escape_string($titul).'\',\''.mysql_real_escape_string($pole).'\', \''.mysql_real_escape_string($text).'\');') or die (mysql_error().'<br />Query: '.$q);
        }
        ?>

<script type="text/javacript">
alert ("Данные внесены");
</script>
        <?php

    }
  }
?>
*}
```

К слову сказать alert ("Данные внесены"); почему то тоже не работает (((((

Comment: а теперь по буквам посмотри < script type="text/javacript">  а именно на слово javacript где тут буква S??? вот и не может понять на каком ты его языке хочешь заставить чтото делать

Answer (score 2):

а давай ка немного изменим то что есть а то глаза мозолит ненужное.

```
$text=$_POST['content'];
$pole=$_POST['pole'];
$titul=$_POST['titul'];
if (!$text || !$pole || !$titul) echo ("Поле не заполнено");
else {
if ( !get_magic_quotes_gpc() ){
// надо экранировать так как автоэкранирование кавычек не включено
$text=stripslashes($text);
$pole=stripslashes($pole);
$titul=stripslashes($titul);  // хотя тут лучше кавычку поменять на спецсимвол.
}
$kuda=array(); // определяем название таблицы по ИД
$kuda[1]="first";
$kuda[5]="news";
$kuda[9]="stat";
if ($kuda[$id]){
//пишем
mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$kuda[$id]} (title, nazv, text) VALUES ('{$titul}','{$pole}','{$text}')") or die (mysql_error());
echo " <script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert (\"Данные внесены\"); </script>";
}
else echo ("нет такого раздела");
}
```

и надо убедиться что есть таблицы first, news, stat, и в них есть данные поля!!!

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, как минимум Вы пропустили

```
 $id=$_POST['id'];
```

Потому что данные передаются у вас через POST, исходя из Вашего примера. Ничто не мешает создать Hidden field в странице с формой, в котором будет передаваться id.

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

А во-вторых, у Вас не хватает закрывающей }, которая должна закрыть первый if

```
if (@$_POST['save']){
```

Comment: $id=$_POST['id']; я не пропустил. он указывается выше по сценарию. Нет. все скобки закрыты правильно. Выложу полный вариант...